# Ansible Mount [Ernno 30] Read-only

Tags: ansible

I am having trouble with a nfs mount in one of my plays.

The Play:

`- path: /.../production/bookinfo
   src: remote_server:/.../linux_shares/bookinfo-images
   fstype: nfs
   opts: rw,timeo=14,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,intr
   state: mounted`

The error:

```
failed: [test-server] (item={u'path': u'/.../production/bookinfo', u'state': u'mounted', u'src': u'dc1-filer-02:/.../linux_shares/bookinfo-images', u'opts': u'rw,timeo=14,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,intr', u'fstype': u'nfs'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"fstype": "nfs", "opts": "rw,timeo=14,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,intr", "path": "/.../production/bookinfo", "src": "remote_server:/.../.../bookinfo-images", "state": "mounted"}, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.10.28.93 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_C2X1_Q/ansible_module_file.py\", line 480, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_C2X1_Q/ansible_module_file.py\", line 359, in main\r\n    changed = module.set_fs_attributes_if_different(file_args, changed, diff)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_C2X1_Q/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 1298, in set_fs_attributes_if_different\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_C2X1_Q/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 1123, in set_mode_if_different\r\nOSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/.../production/bookinfo'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
```

Current State:

`drwxrwxrwx.   4 root    root               4096 Jun 18  2015 bookinfo`

(bookinfo is highlighted green with blue lettering)

This error only happens after the initial run. I run the play a second time and get the error above. The mount is working even with the error, as I am able to 'ls' the directory and access the remote data.

Background Info:

This is on a Centos 7 VM, running python 2.7.5. The folder is present before the mount.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my opts line I had set 'rw' for read/write permissions. My source target was only allowing read only. I corrected this by change 'rw' to 'ro'.

Comment: This sometimes happens to me when using the mount block, when my opts include 'ro'. Still tracking it down.

Comment: @epu I have the same issue